# Why is this not a cartier divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, integer-lattices, divisors-algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

Consider the lattice
$$N=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}^3\mid a+b+c\equiv 0\mod 2\}$$
and the Cone
$$\sigma=Cone(e_1,e_e,e_3)\subset N_{\mathbb{R}}\cong \mathbb{R}^3$$
The associated affine toric variety $X_{\sigma}$ has as its canonical divisor $K_{X_\sigma}=\sum_{i=1}^3-D_i$, where $D_i$ are the torus orbits corresponding to the rays $Cone(e_i)\subset \sigma$. The minimal ray generators are $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2)$, denote them by $u_1,u_2,u_3$ respectively.

We know that for $m\in M=N^\vee$ the corresponding rational function $\chi^m:X_\sigma\to \mathbb{C}$ has:
$$div(\chi^m)=\sum_{i=1}^3 \langle m, u_i\rangle D_i$$

So when we take $m:(a,b,c)\mapsto -\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$ then $m\in N^\vee$, and $div(\chi^m)=\sum_{i=1}^3-D_i$, showing that $K_{X_\sigma}$ is Cartier.

However, in "Toric varieties" by Cox,Little,Schenck, example 11.2.7 the authors claim that $K_{X_\sigma}$ is not Cartier, while $2K_{X_\sigma}$ is.

I don't understand this. They seem to imply that the $m$ I defined is not an element of $N^\vee$, but to me it seems clear that it is... It takes only integer values on the element of $N$, so should be a well defined element of $N^\vee$.

What am I not understanding here?

---

Here's another way of seeing that it should be Cartier. Taking the basis $(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ for $N$ we get an isomorphism $N\cong \mathbb{Z}^3$. Under this isomorphism $\sigma$ corresponds to the cone
$$Cone((-1,1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,-1))\subset\mathbb{R}^3$$

Now the dual lattice is just $\mathbb{Z}^3$, and the pairing is the dot product. Then set $m=(-1,-1,-1)$.

Comment: I have just a small remark : are you sure about your minimal generators ? How do you obtain $(1,1,0) \in N$ from your generators ?

Comment: @N.H. $(1,1,0), (1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ are not contained in $\sigma$; they are just a basis for $N$ (so we can move from the weird "shifted lattice" $N$ to the standard lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$). With respect to this basis the elements $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2)\in N$ are given by $(-1,1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,-1)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm probably a bit rusty (and sorry to bother you !) but I still don't see why $(1,1,0) \notin \sigma$ ? For me since $\sigma = \text{cone}(e_1, e_2,e_3)$ $\sigma$ is the set of $ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3$ with $a,b,c$ positive real numbers right ? So $(1,1,0) = e_1 + e_2$ should be in $\sigma$ ? 
Sorry again to be not very useful. I think your argument looks correct, I can try to read this part and think about it.

Comment: @N.H. No problem! Thanks for thinking about it. You are Right that $(1,1,0)\in\sigma$, but it is not the generator for one of the 1-dimensional Faces of $\sigma$; the ray generated by $(1,1,0)$ Lies in the relative interior of the cone. On the other hand, the $(2,0,0)$ etc generated the 1 dimensional Faces of the cone.

Comment: Ok I got it ! I'll try to think about it.

Comment: I can't find what is wrong in your argument, but I have an argument which proves that $K_X$ is not Cartier. 

A basis of $N$ is given by $v_1 = - e_1 + e_2 + e_3, v_2 =  e_1 - e_2 + e_3$ and $v_3 =  e_1 + e_2 - e_3$. A basis of $M = N^{\vee}$ should be given by vector $w_i$ with $(w_i,v_j ) = \delta_{ij}$. This gives $w_1 = \frac{1}{2}(e_2^* + e_3^* )$, $w_2 = \frac{1}{2}(e_1^* + e_3^*)$ and $w_3 = \frac{1}{2}(e_2^* + e_3^*)$...

Comment: ... and notice that your vector $m = -\frac{1}{2}(w_1 + w_2 + w_3)$ can't be obtained as an integer combinaisons of the $w_i$ so it follows that $K_X$ is not Cartier. On the other hand, as noticed by the textbook $2K_X$ is Cartier.

Comment: @N.H. I'm not sure I understand. It seems to me that your $v_1,v_2,v_3\not\in N$? e.g. for $v_1$ we have $-1+1+1=1\not\equiv 0\mod 2$?

Comment: You are right, a basis of $N$ is given by $v_1 = e_2 + e_3, v_2 = e_1 + e_3, v_3 = e_1 + e_2$. Dual vectors become $w_1 = \frac{1}{2}(-e_1^* + e_2^* + e_3^*), w_2 = \frac{1}{2}(e_1^* - e_2^* + e_3^*)$ and $w_3 = \frac{1}{2}(e_1^* + e_2^* - e_3^*)$. We have $m = -(w_1 + w_2 + w_3)$ so $m \in N^{\vee}$, so it seems that $K_X$ is indeed Cartier... But I am maybe doing again a mistake. Probably it's better to let someone else answer, sorry to be not very useful.

Comment: @N.H. No problem thanks for your time. For what its worth, this last answer you gave seems to make sense to me... Maybe it's a mistake in the book

Comment: I had a class in toric geometry last semester, I can ask my teacher, if he has time I'm sure he'll find the answer pretty quickly.

Comment: @N.H. That would be really nice! On my university I do not have professor that I could ask this too, which I why I resorted to this website. I would be very thankful if you would find the time to ask him:)

Comment: Ok, sorry again, with my last notations $m = \frac{-1}{2} (w_1 + w_2 + w_3)$. So $m \notin N^{\vee}$ but $2m \in N^{\vee}$, assuming you are taking as definition $N^{\vee}$ is the lattice generated by the dual basis of $N$. But I think I'll still send an e-mail to my teacher, just in case.

Comment: @N.H. Are you sure about that? When I add up $w_1+w_2+w_3$ I find $\frac{1}{2}(e_1^*+e_2^*+e_3^*)=m$? Also, $\langle m,v_i \rangle=-1$ for all $i$

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry it's probably too late for me to do math. Hopefully I sended an e-mail to my teacher, I'm sure he'll be able to tell me what is going on. Sorry for all my mistakes and useless messages ><

Comment: @N.H. Again, no problem. I appreciate someone taking the time to think abut this. Its a bit subtle, so easy to make small mistakes.

Comment: I got an answer, it's indeed wrong, because with the lattice they gave, the class group is $Cl(X) \cong \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$ and also even doing a stellar subdivision still leaves the variety singular. This shows that this can't be the good lattice, apparently the correct one to consider is the quotient of $\Bbb C^3$ by the action of $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$ $t \cdot (x,y,z) =  (-x,-y,-z)$.

Comment: @N.H. Thanks for the answer! If you write it as an actual answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $K_{X_{\sigma}}$ is Cartier. Your argument is correct, and the claim stated in the book is wrong. They also claim that $Cl(X) \cong \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$. But the rays generators $u_i$ verify $u_i = (f_1 + f_2 + f_3) - f_i$ where $f_i = (1,1,1) - e_i$ is the basis of your lattice. In particular, we have an exact sequence $$ 0 \to M \to \oplus_{\rho_i} \Bbb Z D_i \to Cl(X) \to 0$$ where the first map is the matrix $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & - 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & - 1\end{pmatrix}$

So we have $$ Cl(X) \cong \text{coker}(\alpha) = \{(a,b,c) \in \Bbb Z^3 : a = b + c, b = a + c, c = a + b\} \cong \{(a,b) : 2a = 2 b = 0\} \cong \Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$$ which shows that they probably wrote the wrong lattice.

Comment: A little more remark : my teacher told me that the correct space to consider should be the quotient of $\Bbb C^3$ by the action of $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z : t \cdot(x,y,z) = (-x,-y,-z)$. Cox gives a way of finding the lattice from the action of a cyclic group in the case of surface but I am not sure how to adapt the argument. My teacher also suggested that the good lattice was $N = \{a +b = a + c = 0 \mod 2 \}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer and contacting your professor. I'll see if this $N$ does indeed produce a $K_X$ that is not Cartier, while $2K_X$ is.

Comment: Ok, if you find the correct answer don't hesitate to write it as an answer, I'll be very glad to see the computations.